# How to change selectively the post-note comma in a citation using biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, citing

I'm using `biblatex` for my citations and references. In some citations I'd like to change the comma for any other symbol that I want. How can I do this?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[
citestyle=authoryear-comp,
bibstyle=authoryear,
giveninits=true,
maxcitenames=2
]{biblatex}

%References
\begin{filecontents*}{references22.bib}
@Article{Ho_1899,
  author   = {Ho, Lionel and Dreyfus, J. and Boyer, J. and Lowe, T. and Bustamante, H. and Duker, P.},
  title    = {Example article},
  year     = {1899}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{references22.bib}
\begin{document}

\textcite[some words]{Ho_1899}\\
\parencite[some words]{Ho_1899}\par%
%
In the next 2 citations, I'd like to change the comma for ~-~ and "."\par
%
\textcite[~-~some words]{Ho_1899}\\
\parencite[. Some words]{Ho_1899}\par
%
Expected result\par
%
Ho et al. (1899~-~some words)\\
(Ho et al. 1899. Some words)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please Check the edited version, (natbib=true doesn't needed and added a second better option that doesn't break the comma of the original command)

Comment: @DanielalenciaC. Feel free to select the provided answer of mowe that is using the correct (provided by biblatex) method of changing the delim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This answer is something that many people would imagine as a solution and thus it is here (I will not delete) in order to demonstrate possible problems of such a definition. So, please the last part labeled "moewe's example" in order to understand why this method should be avoided**

**Section 1:**

A hack, but **it will break the ability of adding a second optional argument** in your `\textcite` and `\parencite` comands (if they can "afford" one second argument):

**Edit: (both codes)** Changed in order to not break (redefine) the original commands' behavior but to use another command name in order to help the discussion with @moewe untill delete the answer.

**For @moewe:** I also suppose no comma will be added in the second (the mandatory) argument of these two new commands and would like to know what would be the problem in such a definition.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[
citestyle=authoryear-comp,
bibstyle=authoryear,
giveninits=true,
maxcitenames=2,
]{biblatex}

%References
\begin{filecontents*}{references22.bib}
@Article{Ho_1899,
  author   = {Ho, Lionel and Dreyfus, J. and Boyer, J. and Lowe, T. and Bustamante, H. and Duker, P.},
  title    = {Example article},
  year     = {1899}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand\mytextcite[2][]{\citeauthor{#2}(\citeyear{#2}#1)}
\newcommand\myparencite[2][]{(\cite{#2}#1)}
\addbibresource{references22.bib}
\begin{document}
\mytextcite[some words]{Ho_1899}\\
\myparencite[some words]{Ho_1899}\par%
%
In the next 2 citations, I'd like to change the comma for ~-~ and "."\par
%
\mytextcite[~-~some words]{Ho_1899}\\
\myparencite[. Some words]{Ho_1899}\par
%
Expected result\par
%
Ho et al. (1899~-~some words)\\
(Ho et al. 1899. Some words)

\end{document}
```

PS: You have to add comma manually in the above code's first two citations.

**Section 2:**

Code that will work for the two first citations too:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[
citestyle=authoryear-comp,
bibstyle=authoryear,
giveninits=true,
maxcitenames=2,
]{biblatex}

%References
\begin{filecontents*}{references22.bib}
@Article{Ho_1899,
  author   = {Ho, Lionel and Dreyfus, J. and Boyer, J. and Lowe, T. and Bustamante, H. and Duker, P.},
  title    = {Example article},
  year     = {1899}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\def\mydelim{,~}
\newcommand\mytextcite[2][]{\citeauthor{#2}(\citeyear{#2}\mydelim#1)}
\newcommand\myparencite[2][]{(\cite{#2}\mydelim#1)}
\addbibresource{references22.bib}
\begin{document}
\mytextcite[some words]{Ho_1899}\\
\myparencite[some words]{Ho_1899}\par%
%
In the next 2 citations, I'd like to change the comma for ~-~ and "."\par
%

\def\mydelim{~.~}
\mytextcite[some words]{Ho_1899}\\
\def\mydelim{.~}
\myparencite[Some words]{Ho_1899}\par
%
Expected result\par
%
Ho et al. (1899~-~some words)\\
(Ho et al. 1899. Some words)

\end{document}
```

The given result for these examples are the expected results:

[image]

**moewe's example**: (read his last comment too)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\def\mydelim{,~}
\newcommand\mytextcite[2][]{\citeauthor{#2}(\citeyear{#2}\mydelim#1)}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson} \cite{sigfridsson}

\mytextcite{nussbaum} \mytextcite{nussbaum} % no "ibid"

\cite{sigfridsson} % incorrect "ibid."

\citereset
\cite{sigfridsson} \cite{sigfridsson}

\textcite{nussbaum} \textcite{nussbaum} % correct "ibid"

\cite{sigfridsson} % no "ibid."
\end{document}
```

Comment: I strongly prefer solutions that do not redefine the cite commands in such a way. Not only does this approach not allow for the second option `prenote` argument, it also has a hard time dealing with multiple citations: Try `\textcite{sigfridsson,worman}`. In its current definition the citations will also produce a spurious postnote punctuation if there is no optional argument: Try `\textcite{sigfridsson}`. Furthermore, the combination of several `\cite` commands into one `\(re)newcommand` can mess up citation tracking (which would be important for 'ibid.' or backrefs).

Comment: `-comp` features are also disabled: Cite `\textcite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}` (and compare that with `\cite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}`). Oh, I just realised: Try `\textcite{knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c}` and compare it with `\cite{knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c}`. The disambiguation letters are missing! That is a serious issue as it will make the citation impossible to pin down.

Comment: Thanks , @mowe, I was thinking to not redefine the command but just give a new name. Sure would give less problems and I could fix it to accept more arguments, but I am going to delete the answer. I would like to know what this: "the combination of several \cite commands into one \(re)newcommand can mess up citation tracking" supposed to mean. (I mean that I would  like to understand why this problem would come up) Sure it would not show the correct -suggested- order for multiple citation in one command and this would change the order of an unsrt-style bibliography etc. For 1 inner argument?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/moewew/67866c6ddbcc32a3b0c201f99ba9af23 shows an issue that would arise with 'ibid.' styles.

Comment: The key here is that full citation commands such as `\cite`, `\textcite`, `\parencite` are tracked by `biblatex` (i.e. they set the last cited key, author, year for 'ibid.' and the like, `biblatex` remembers the page number for `backref`, the citations are indexed, ...). The lower-level `\citeauthor`, `\citetitle` etc. usually do no such thing, they are not tracked and exist 'outside' or are transparent for the real cite commands. If you now use the low-level command to recreate a real cite command, this can mess up the tracking expectations.

Comment: Thanks @moewe. I added your example in my answer and finally will not delete it since seems usefull to me

Answer (score 6):

The command that controls the punctuation before the postnote is called `\postnotedelim`. You can redefine it as you see fit. If you only want to change the punctuation locally for the next cite command, it is best to wrap the redefinition into `\AtNextCite`. It may come in handy to define a new command for that to avoid having to type that much.

If there is a rule/an algorithm behind the changes to the punctuation, it might be possible to automate the changes. Starting with the next `biblatex` release `postnotedelim` will be a context-sensitive delimiter (https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/869), which means that it will be very simple to define different delimiters for `\parencite` and `\textcite`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newcommand*{\SetNextPostnoteDelim}[1]{%
  \AtNextCite{\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\textcite[some words 01]{sigfridsson}

\parencite[some words 02]{sigfridsson}

% \AtNextCite applies only to the next citation
\AtNextCite{\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addspace\textendash\space}}
\textcite[some words 03]{sigfridsson}

\parencite[some words 04]{sigfridsson}

\AtNextCite{\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addperiod\space}}
\parencite[Some words 05]{sigfridsson}

\textcite[some words 06]{sigfridsson}

% \AtNextCite packed up in a handy command
\SetNextPostnoteDelim{\addspace\textendash\space}
\textcite[some words 03']{sigfridsson}

\parencite[some words 04']{sigfridsson}

\SetNextPostnoteDelim{\addperiod\space}
\parencite[Some words 05']{sigfridsson}

\textcite[some words 06']{sigfridsson}

% a simple \renewcommand applies from now until the next change
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addspace\textendash\space}
\textcite[some words 07]{sigfridsson}

\parencite[some words 08]{sigfridsson}

\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addperiod\space}
\parencite[Some words 09]{sigfridsson}

\textcite[Some words 10]{sigfridsson}

% manual approach: provide the punctuation in the postnote
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{}
\textcite[~-~some words 11]{sigfridsson}

\parencite[. Some words 12]{sigfridsson}
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson and Ryde (1998, some words 01)//(Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998, some words 02)//Sigfridsson and Ryde (1998 – some words 03)//(Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998, some words 04)//(Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998. Some words 05)//Sigfridsson and Ryde (1998, some words 06)//Sigfridsson and Ryde (1998 – some words 03’)//(Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998, some words 04’)//(Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998. Some words 05’)//Sigfridsson and Ryde (1998, some words 06’)//Sigfridsson and Ryde (1998 – some words 07)//(Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998 – some words 08)//(Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998. Some words 09)//Sigfridsson and Ryde (1998. Some words 10)//Sigfridsson and Ryde (1998 - some words 11)//(Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998. Some words 12)]