# How to add an MLA style in text citation with page number

Tags: biblatex, citing, biblatex-mla

I've been trying to create a citation using \parencite that includes the page number. The command I used was \parencite[23]{columbus} which gave me (Columbus 23). How can I get it to out put as: (Columbus, 23).

Minimum Working Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel, csquotes, xpatch}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=mla-new, natbib]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mla.bib}



\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}



\centerline{Paper Title}


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \parencite[23]{colu92}
\newpage



\centerline{Works Cited}

\printbibliography[heading=none]
  
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
\}
```

Answer (score 1):

The punctuation before the postnote is controlled by `postnotedelim`, which `biblatex-mla` sets to `\addspace`. Unfortunately, it is not enough to just set this delimiter to `\addcomma\space`. `biblatex-mla` has removed reference to `postnotedelim` in many places, so we have to re-add them

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=mla-new]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat{postnotedelim}{\addcomma\space}

\renewbibmacro*{postnote}{%
  \iffieldundef{postnote}%
    {}
    {\setunit{\printdelim{postnotedelim}}%%
     \ifbool{cbx@hyperpages}%
      {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[ibidpostnote]{postnote}}}%
      {\printfield[ibidpostnote]{postnote}}}}%

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite[380]{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite[12-14]{worman}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sigfridsson and Ryde, 380) ipsum (Worman, 12-14)]

Answer (score 0):

Following the advice of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/478292/17360 I would add `\newcommand\myparencite[2][]{(\cite{#2},~#1)}` to the preamble and then use `\myparencite[23]{colu92}`. That produces then the desired solution:

[image: preview]